# Do I need a hotel reservation when entering the Schengen area?

Tags: schengen, denmark, proof-of-accommodation

I'll be visiting Copenhagen next month for 10 days. I've already got my visa, but I've got a question about my hotel reservation. A friend has kindly offered me a spare room to stay at (Amager Strand, conveniently close to the airport as well) so I am thinking about canceling my hotel booking.

From my previous experience, I know that the airport officials usually ask to see the hotel reservation. If I were to cancel the reservation, and tell them that I'll be staying with my friend instead, what kind of information would they require?

I tried searching online but didn't find a similar situation, except for some guy asking if he could produce the reservation copy for the canceled booking!

Comment: There is a finite possibility the IO will suspect that the original booking was a contrivance. I would have your friend be in the airport when you arrive.

Comment: Thanks, Gayot. But I don't see how the IO at the airport will know that. I wont be showing my canceled booking of course.

Comment: You never know with IO. To be safe, just pay the hotel for one day and move to your friends place after that.

Comment: “IO” is British terminology, the Schengen terminology is “border guard”.

Answer (score 2):

From your very experience, border officials can and do ask for proof of accommodation. Having included that with your visa application, it might be unwise to simply cancel. Telling a border official that you're now planning to stay with a friend might be a negative tick mark, as @GayotFow wisely points out.

You can:

- keep the reservation (whether you check in and shorten your stay to one night, or cancel after you enter and pay any cancellation fee);
- cancel and obtain an invitation letter from your friend (making sure it includes all contact information and, perhaps, the reason for the last minute invite, as opposed to when you were planning your trip and visa application);
- cancel the reservation in advance (and take your chances that you won't be asked about it when you present for entry at the border, and if you are, it won't be an issue and, if it is, not one that results in the IO refusing entry).